# Wordpress Plugin: Check if table exists, create table and insert large amounts of data

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've currently got a wordpress plugin that was working beautifully, but am now faced with the issue of making sure it is deployable across any server instance. Basically I'm trying to make it so the plugin will create the tables I need as well as inserting the large amounts of data (11k+ rows) automatically upon activation of the plug-in. I have the exported sql file that contains all the tables (3.8MB).

The code I plan on implementing and customizing is below, but I'm unsure on how to reference the SQL file, and create the 5 separate tables in addition to inserting all that data.

```
//action hook for plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'callback_plugin' );
//callback function
function callback_plugin(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "your-table-name";
    if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
                id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                name tinytext NOT NULL
                );";
        //reference to upgrade.php file
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
    }
}
```

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on if you're deploying this on your own servers, or unknown servers.

That's a LOT of SQL to do on one run. I'd consider building it more like a queue system and runs via an AJAX based import, ie: Importing row 1 of 11,000 or whatever. You could probably do batches of 10 rows for example.

So somebody activates plugin.

Redirect them to "Install screen" saying "this may take a few minutes"

Hit install button

jQuery now loops through a list and doing admin-ajax adding 10 (for example) rows at a time, and then show a message when done.

If you were to try this on a cheap shared hosting company, you'd have timeouts, partial data imported etc.. a bit of a mess!